# How can I get all data when there is None(no data in my table) (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql

I want to select all data from Ptbl.
(if there are no data in Ptbl which has price 20000, i want to select it with none or ifnull() )

but price(20000) is not in Ptbl.
so when I execute this query

```
create table Ptbl
(
name varchar(10) not null,
product varchar(10) not null,
price Int not null
);


insert into Ptbl values('myname', 'monitor', 12000);
insert into Ptbl values('myname', 'mouse', 8000);
insert into Ptbl values('myname', 'keyboard', 10000);


 select name, price, ifnull(product,'no') as product
 from Ptbl
 where 
      name= 'myname' and 
      (
      price = 12000 or
      price = 20000
      );
```

i want to make 12000 output => monitor

and

20000 output => None

like

```
+------+-------+---------+
| name | price | product |
+------+-------+---------+
|myname|12000  | monitor |
|myname|20000  |   no    |
+------+-------+---------+
```

but this query make

```
+------+-------+---------+
| name | price | product |
+------+-------+---------+
|myname|12000  | monitor |
+------+-------+---------+
```

is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO, and desired output for it.

Comment: Please see [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056). It will help both you and users that want to answer your Question :)

Comment: Please share more details - you state that "price is not in Ptbl", but according to the table structure and the sampe data, it is

Comment: hmm.. i'm not good at english.. so i try to explaint my problem very hard.. but it's not good to see you sorry